# No loggin, no Ports except 21

Tags: ssh, apache-httpd, hardware, webserver, freeze

Occasionally the server seems to freeze. But we find out, that FTP on port 21 is still available, while the Ports 80, 8080, 10000, our SSH-Port, which is not 22, and 443 are unavailable.
Also the loggin stops. All logfiles do have gaps during that period of time.
The only chance to get all working again is a hardware reset, which will restart the machine.

The mcelog shows some bad working ventilation.

Authlog and syslog are showing the usual suspects, but nothing which should bring such behaviour.

Does anybody has had a behaviour like this before?

Because it is that strange, I really do not know what to present other than the start of the gap in syslog

````
May  6 05:48:35 server4 kernel: [74230.825498] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=90:1b:0e:93:23:8f:00:31:46:0d:3b:85:08:00 SRC=216.249.101.105 DST=88.99.44.77 LEN=457 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=29755 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5060 DPT=5060 LEN=437
May  6 05:48:35 server4 postfix/smtpd[31939]: connect from unknown[88.148.12.67]
May  6 05:48:35 server4 kernel: [74230.939036] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=90:1b:0e:93:23:8f:00:31:46:0d:3b:85:08:00 SRC=178.128.220.214 DST=88.99.44.67 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=42751 PROTO=TCP SPT=48441 DPT=25579 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
May  6 05:48:35 server4 kernel: [74230.947378] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=90:1b:0e:93:23:8f:00:31:46:0d:3b:85:08:00 SRC=80.82.64.146 DST=88.99.44.65 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=250 ID=47541 PROTO=TCP SPT=44343 DPT=3638 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
May  6 05:48:35 server4 kernel: [74230.939036] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=90:1b:0e:93:23:8f:00:31:46:0d:3b:85:08:00 SRC=178.128.220.214 DST=88.99.44.67 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=42751 PROTO=TCP SPT=48441 DPT=25579 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
May  6 05:48:35 server4 kernel: [74230.947378] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=90:1b:0e:93:23:8f:00:31:46:0d:3b:85:08:00 SRC=80.82.64.146 DST=88.99.44.65 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=250 ID=47541 PROTO=TCP SPT=44343 DPT=3638 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
May  6 07:31:42 server4 systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
May  6 07:31:42 server4 systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
May  6 07:31:42 server4 systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.```

Code from mcelog
```Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 2
CPU 4 THERMAL EVENT TSC 3e4ca482cdde
TIME 1651835101 Fri May  6 13:05:01 2022
Processor 4 below trip temperature. Throttling disabled
Running trigger `unknown-error-trigger'
mcelog: Too many trigger children running already
STATUS 88020a82 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c0a APICID 1 SOCKETID 0
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 94
mcelog: warning: 16 bytes ignored in each record
mcelog: consider an update
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 4 THERMAL EVENT TSC 3e4ca4583284
TIME 1651835101 Fri May  6 13:05:01 2022
Processor 4 heated above trip temperature. Throttling enabled.
Please check your system cooling. Performance will be impacted
Running trigger `unknown-error-trigger'
mcelog: Too many trigger children running already```
````

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's clearly a "Hardware event. This is not a software error"

Comment: That means the log in mce and might only refer to to the heating problem, possible not to the freeze of the ports